# Circular reference functions in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, circular-reference

Lets say I wish to create an OCaml program which takes a list of integers and creates the sum of double the first item, triple the second item, double the third item, and so on..

```
let rec doubler some_list =
  match some_list with
  | [] -> 0;
  | head::tail -> (head * 2) + (tripler tail);;
                               
let rec tripler some_list =
  match some_list with
  | [] -> 0;
  | head::tail -> (head * 3) + (doubler tail);;

let maths_stuff some_list =
  doubler some_list;;

let foo = maths_stuff [1;2;3;4;5;6] (* Should be 54 *)
```

Currently I get a `Error: Unbound value tripler` error because OCaml doesn't know what it is, but I can't reorder the two functions without having the same problem with `doubler`.

Whats the syntax for specifying a circular dependency between two functions? All I've found with Google is discussions of circular dependencies between modules during the build process, which isn't what I'm after.

Many TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutually recursive items (values, types, classes, classes types, modules) need to be grouped with `and`:

```ml
let rec doubler = function
  | [] -> 0;
  | head::tail -> head * 2 + tripler tail
                              
and tripler = function
  | [] -> 0;
  | head::tail -> head * 3 + doubler tail
```